# Truncate file with a path relative to a directory/file descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, operating-system

Many methods of the `os` module (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)) support paths relative to file descriptors (`dir_fd`), for example the `unlink` method:

```
os.unlink(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

I have been relying on this feature in a few cases, though it is not supported for all file-related methods of `os`. It's missing for `truncate` (until and including Python 3.7), for instance:

```
os.truncate(path, length)
```

How can I work around this issue?

My best idea so far is to explicitly open the file:

```
fd = os.open(path, flags = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_TRUNC, ... , dir_fd=dir_fd)
os.ftruncate(fd, length)
os.close(fd)
```

I was wondering whether there was a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`truncate` does not have a `dir_fd` parameter, because there is no `truncateat` system call, which would be required for that. See [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55765181/1672565).

The proper and only feasible solution actually is:

```py
def truncate(path, length, dir_fd = None):
    fd = os.open(path, flags = os.O_WRONLY, dir_fd = dir_fd)
    os.ftruncate(fd, length)
    os.close(fd)
```

Differing from my initial question, one MUST NOT specify mode `os.O_TRUNC` when opening the file. If one does that, the file will be truncated to zero by just opening it, which is by no means intended.