# How to implement something similar to "truncateat"?

Tags: linux, posix, system-calls, glibc

While researching [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52871892/1672565) I came across the fact that in POSIX (and Linux) there simply is not a `truncateat` system call.

Certain system calls like for instance `unlink` have an equivalent alternative method with an added `at` suffix at the end of their names, i.e. `unlinkat`. The difference between those methods is that the variations with the `at` suffix accept an additional argument, a file descriptor pointing to a directory. Therefore, a relative path passed into `unlinkat` is not relative to the current working directory but instead relative to the provided file descriptor (an open directory). This is really useful under certain circumstances.

Looking at `truncate`, there only is `ftruncate` next to it. `truncate` works on paths - absolute or relative to the current working directory. `ftruncate` directly works on an open file handle - without any path being specified. There is no `truncateat`.

A lot of libraries (various "alternative" C-libraries) do what I did and mimic `tuncateat` by using an `openat`-`ftruncate`-`close`-sequence. This works, in most cases, except ...

I ran into the following issue. It took me months to figure out what was happening. Tested on Linux, different 3.X and 4.X kernels. Imagine two processes (not threads):

- Process "A"
- Process "B"

Now imagine the following sequence of events (pseudo code):

```
A: fd = open(path = 'filename', mode = write)
A: ftruncate(fd, 100)
A: write(fd, 'abc')
B: truncate('filename', 200)
A: write(fd, 'def')
A: close(fd)
```

The above works just fine. Just after process "A" has the file opened, set its size to 100 and written some stuff into it, process "B" re-sets its size to 200. Then process "A" continues. At the end, the file has a size of 200 and contains "abcdef" at its beginning followed by zero-bytes.

Now, let's try and mimic something like `truncateat`:

```
A: fd_a = open(path = 'filename', mode = write)
A: ftruncate(fd_a, 100)
A: write(fd_a, 'abc')
B: fd_b = openat(dirfd = X, path = 'filename', mode = write | truncate)
B: ftruncate(fd_b, 200)
B: close(fd_b)
A: write(fd_a, 'def')
A: close(fd_a)
```

My file has a length of 200, ok. It starts with three zero-bytes, not ok, then the "def", then then again zero-bytes. I have just lost the first write from process "A" while the "def" technically landed at the correct position (three bytes in, as if I had called `seek(fd_a, 3)` before writing it).

I can work with the first sequence of operations just fine. But in my use case, I can not rely on paths relative the current working directory as far as process "B" is concerned. I really want to work with paths relative to a file descriptor. How can achieve that - without running into the issue demonstrated in the second sequence of operations? Calling `fsync` from process "A" just after `write(fd_a, 'abc')` does not solve this.

Comment: Are you saying that `truncate` *would* have worked in your case?

Comment: @thatotherguy I tested it. It does in fact work.

Comment: So is the problem just that you opened the file with mode=truncate, thereby doing two truncations (first at byte 0 and then at 200)?

Comment: @thatotherguy Does "open in truncate mode" imply that there is a truncate to zero?

Comment: @thatotherguy That would be a really silly mistake. Let me try without mode=truncate ...

Comment: @thatotherguy If I just open in write mode (without truncate mode), it works ... thanks. I guess I need to study up on how exactly open works. Do you want to put this together into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your second case overwrites everything with zeroes is that mode=truncate (i.e. `openat(.., O_TRUNC)`) will first truncate the file to length 0.

If you instead `ftruncate` to 200 immediately without first truncating to 0, the existing data up until that point will remain untouched.